# Is the wave behind a duck a parabola or a hyperbola?

Tags: conic-sections, mathematical-physics

I tried to solve this problem when I saw some ducks in a lake. Suppose a duck moves along a straight line with a constant speed. Is the wave behind it a parabola or half of a hyperbola. I checked the definitions of them but still have no clue about the problem. Should the roughly V shaped wave be a parabola or one branch of a hyperbola with the duck being the vertex?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMzuj.jpg)

Comment: Probably neither. In a perfect world, if the amplitude of the waves did not die down, you would get a sinusoidal pattern. A parabola would make a good approximation for part of a wavelength, though: consider the second-degree Taylor polynomial at the extrema of the sine wave. ([Desmos visual,](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jwsawzbphz)) Dampening the amplitude probably results in a function behaving more like $\sin(x)/x$, though.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This was apparently studied extensively(?) by [Lord Kelvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_(physics)#Kelvin_wake_pattern). You might consider searching for [papers on the topic](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C14&q=kelvin+wake+pattern) to find more technical info on the phenomenon.

Comment: @PrincessEev I *believe* that the asker is talking about the wake pattern, and not the "waves".

Answer (score 5):

The theoretical shape of the wake behind an object traveling in water at constant speed is called the Kelvin wake. It is a waveform that is trapped in a wedge that Kelvin showed has half-angular width $\arcsin(1/3)=19.472 ^\circ$.

However recent literature suggests that the actual observed angle has some dependence on speed.

"While the half-angle which encloses a Kelvin ship wave pattern is commonly accepted to be 19.47°, recent observations and calculations for sufficiently fast-moving ships suggest that the apparent wake angle decreases with ship speed. "

Pethiyagoda, Ravindra, Scott W. McCue, and Timothy J. Moroney. "*What is the Apparent Angle of a Kelvin Ship Wave Pattern?*" **Journal of Fluid Mechanics**, vol. 758, 2014, pp. 468-485.

Answer (score 0):

A lazy duck will generate a parabolic wake. But the duck in your picture is supersonic -- it is swimming faster than the speed of ripple propagation in the local medium -- so it generates a hyperbolic wake. (This is why we get sonic booms.)

Comment: Thank you. But could you develop it further a little bit about the speed of a duck and the ripple propagation?

Comment: The speed of ripple propagation in a liquid is not at all the same thing as the speed of sound in that liquid. The speed of sound in water is 1500m/s, the claim that the duck is supersonic is itself hyperbolic. A sonic boom has a hyperbolic wavefront when it intersects the ground at a different height, but at the same elevation of the plane (in this case, the surface of the water is analogous), it's just two straight lines.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie: I agree with almost everything you say -- I was not claiming that the duck in the picture must be travelling at 3,350 mph. But note that (half of) a hyperbola looks like two straight lines from far enough away. If you include the bow wave of the duck (or the aircraft), it better approximates a hyperbola than two straight lines.